# Using .htaccess to redirect http to https - causing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS using lets-proxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, https, lets-encrypt

I use a service called lets-proxy2 (https://github.com/rekby/lets-proxy2) to automatically get and renew certificates from Let's Encrypt.

This works well, however when trying to redirect http to https within the .htaccess file, I'm getting an infinite redirect loop which is throwing up the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in the browser.

I've tried several different RewriteConds and RewriteRules, I get the same issue with all.

The current .htaccess file I'm using is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} !(^.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I need to force https to make sure all http traffic is redircted to https, however currently attempting this with a .htaccess file wont work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing your browser's cache. And check.

Comment: And also change `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} !(^.+)` to `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`

Comment: I see that there is a issue created there about this already https://github.com/rekby/lets-proxy2/issues/140

Comment: You could use certbot instead of lets-proxy. It also renews your certs automatically.

Comment: I tried clearing cookies and cache, no luck. I also tried that updated .htaccess file rule - it was still creating an endless loop.

Comment: It looks like there has now been a fix put in place to handle this, so I will test today and feedback on here if all is well incase anyone else encounters the same or similar issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm familiar with certbot and do use this on some projects. However, I needed a fully automated way to get and renew certificates.

Comment: CERTBOT can automatically keep track of your certs and renew them I believe. I am pretty sure. I've used it to create certs. I've heard that you can also get 4096 keys with it. And other customizations.

Comment: Yes, I've used certbot to auto renew in the past. The problem is, you need to manually set up the cert first time around for any domain. Lets-proxy2 actually creates the cert for the domain the first time the domain name is accessed and then renews as and when necessary. It's pretty cool actually.

Answer (score 1):

The author of lets-proxy2 has actually released a fix that solves the problem here - https://github.com/rekby/lets-proxy2/issues/140.

There were no default headers being set, so it was just ending up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, the rule/condition you posted above (`%{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} !(^.+)`) - which you say you needed in v1 - doesn't really make sense. The condition is only successful (ie. the redirect occurs) when the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is empty (or not set). If the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is being set at all by the proxy server then it is _never_ empty (or it shouldn't be) - so the redirect would never happen. If the header is not set then you get a redirect loop (since there's no reason why it would be set on the redirected request).

Comment: ...That is unless the proxy used a very non-standard implementation and only set the header on HTTPS requests? But that would strictly be incorrect - but is the only way that the above rule would "work" as intended. The regex/CondPattern `!(^.+)` is also overly "complex/inefficient". It's the same as simply `!.` or `^$` - since you are only testing if it's _empty_.

Comment: The rule was not required in lets-proxy vs 1 but rather we used it to force https. This was then causing an endless loop in lets-proxy vs 2. The author of that software said this was because it was not setting a default header (which vs 1 did).